# How does OkHttp get Json string?

Tags: java, http, okhttp, embedded-jetty

***Solution***:
It was a mistake on my side.

The right way is **response.body().string()** other than **response.body.toString()**

Im using Jetty servlet, the URL is`http://172.16.10.126:8789/test/path/jsonpage`, every time request this URL it will return

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

It shows up when type the url into a browser, unfortunately it shows kind of memory address other than the json string when I request with `Okhttp`.

```
TestActivity﹕ com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RealResponseBody@537a7f84
```

The Okhttp code Im using:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Can anyone helpe?

Comment: It constructs String object from the char bytes and charset.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski  thanks! It was my own mistake. I replaced `response.body().string()` to `response.body().toString()`...

Comment: @haifzhan Thanks for clarifying the use of response.body().string() instead of response.body().toString()

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
try {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(urls[0])
        .build();
    Response responses = null;

    try {
        responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String jsonData = responses.body().string();
    JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("employees");

    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object     = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
    }
}
```

Example add to your columns:

```
JCol employees  = new employees();
colums.Setid(object.getInt("firstName"));
columnlist.add(lastName);
```

Comment: I'm now getting the exception: `org.json.JSONException: Value okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@aeb56f3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: very easy mistake is to confuse  `.string()` with '.toString()'

Comment: You should specify where you get the objects from, like the JSONObject. please, Include the imports too.

Comment: I'm trying to do simple request using Okhttp (3.x.x), is this the basic for request?

Comment: `responses.body().string()` can be called just one time <br/> use this code directlty :  

`//String jsonData = responses.body().string();
JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(responses.body().string());`

Comment: how can we get multiple fields as objects. Eg - can we get another field like employees?

Answer (score 28):

I am also faced the same issue

use this code:

```
// notice string() call
String resStr = response.body().string();    
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(resStr);
```

it definitely works

Comment: Thank's a lot! Interesting that there is no info about string() method in documentation. But it actually works

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. This helped me out a lot! Strange how I could not find this anywhere else on the internet!

Comment: Thank u so much.It's strange about string() but it works great!

Comment: For OKHttp3 GraphQL responses that include the `data` and `error` object, this also applies.

Comment: Isn't adding toString() redundant? You should only require response.body().string(). That returns back String.

Answer (score 24):

As I observed in my code.
If once the value is fetched of body from Response, its become blank.

```
String str = response.body().string();  // {response:[]}

String str1  = response.body().string();  // BLANK
```

So I believe after fetching once the value from body, it become empty.

Suggestion : Store it in String, that can be used many time.

Comment: Thank you so much. Been trying to figure out this for a while and none of the above answers actually helped because I was first logging whole body and then trying to get the string and this was actually the issue.

Comment: that is correct. What a silly situation

Answer (score 9):

I hope you managed to obtain the json data from the json string.

Well I think this will be of help

```
try {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(urls[0])
    .build();
Response responses = null;

try {
    responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

String jsonData = responses.body().string();

JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("employees");

//define the strings that will temporary store the data
String fname,lname;

//get the length of the json array
int limit = Jarray.length()

//datastore array of size limit
String dataStore[] = new String[limit];

for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    JSONObject object     = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

    fname = object.getString("firstName");
    lname = object.getString("lastName");

    Log.d("JSON DATA", fname + " ## " + lname);

    //store the data into the array
    dataStore[i] = fname + " ## " + lname;
}

//prove that the data was stored in the array      
 for (String content ; dataStore ) {
        Log.d("ARRAY CONTENT", content);
    }
```

Remember to use AsyncTask or SyncAdapter(IntentService), to prevent getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException

Also import the okhttp library in your build.gradle

`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'`

Comment: Can I use `DownloadManager` together with this?

Comment: If you noticed, once you download a file, there will be a blinking white down arrow at your statusbar. Indicating you download something. That is handle by `DownloadManager`

Answer (score 3):

Below code is for getting data from online server using GET method and okHTTP library for android kotlin...

Log.e("Main",**response.body!!.string()**)

in above line !! is the thing using which you can get the json from response body

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
            val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                .get()
                .url("http://172.16.10.126:8789/test/path/jsonpage")
                .addHeader("", "")
                .addHeader("", "")
                .build()
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    // Handle this
                    Log.e("Main","Try again latter!!!")
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    // Handle this
                    Log.e("Main",response.body!!.string())
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more observation. You can call .string() method only once. If you try to call it twice, it will give you illegal state exception.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).