# Why can't I instantiate a JSONObject in Java (string cannot be converted to map)

Tags: java

I am reading a Stackoverflow post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221555/how-does-okhttp-get-json-string)), I am writing the code contained in the answer but I can't instantiate a JSONObject. The post don't specify where JSONObject comes from so imported it as follows:

```
  import org.json.simple.JSONObject;  

  String jsonData = response.body().string();
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData); //jsonData marked as the soruce of the error and the message "incompatible types cannot convert string to map" shows.
```

Comment: what do you think 'String cannot be converted to Map' means?

Comment: What bugs me is not the error message, which is clear, but the fact that it seems it is not working only for me.

Comment: What exact string is your `jsonData`?

Comment: I am not getting a runtime error, I am getting a compilation error, so I don't think the string matters.

Comment: @DiegoAlves 'String cannot be converted to Map', so yes, the String matters. not the content, but the type. you are somewhere trying to do Map<?,?> test = "hello"; (or similar), which, obviously, can not work

Comment: Check your stacktrace, check that the version of your library has a constructor of JSONObject that accepts a String, ...

Comment: Make sure you're using the right JSONObject. The one in package org.json.simple is not the one you want to use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `org.json.JSONObject`. That one has a constructor that takes a String.

Comment: I am new to java I see that is very common to find classes with the same name that come from different packages.