# Get values from OkHttp Response Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I am trying to get values from a OkHttp response body string but am getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

The response body string looks like this( **response.body().toString()** )

```
        {
            "MerchantRequestID":"000000000000",
            "CheckoutRequestID":"170220202216211826",
            "ResponseCode": "0",
            "ResponseDescription":"Request accepted for processing",
            "CustomerMessage":"Request accepted for processing"
        }
```

I am parsing it like this

```
Gson g = new Gson();
SuccessResponse resp = g.fromJson(resp.body().toString(),SuccessResponse.class);
```

How do i get the individual values from the response string.

Comment: Looks like the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221555/how-does-okhttp-get-json-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create POJO with that fields (manually or using services like [this](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) ). Then you can create instance of your POJO this way :

```
String json = "{'MerchantRequestID': '000000000000','CheckoutRequestID':'170220202216211826','ResponseCode': '0','ResponseDescription':'Request accepted for processing','CustomerMessage':'Request accepted for processing'}";
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Example example = g.fromJson(json, Example.class);
    System.out.print(example.getCheckoutRequestID());
```

Comment: I have updated by question, i am now getting a java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ error

Comment: Updated for you. The example works properly. Make sure that your class is declared properly.